# How i can display image from the Absolute Uri(C:\1.jpg) source in XAML WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I tried to solve this problem in different ways like this:

XAML:

```
<Image Name="immage" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding UrlString}"/>
```

XAML.CS:

```
this.UrlString = new Uri("D:/1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute).AbsoluteUri;
```

I only display my images when i set Relative Uri like this: "/Assets/1.jpg"
but i want use Absolute Uri, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use absolute Uri like “C:\1.jpg” or “D:\1.jpg” in Windows Runtime App. Apps can access certain file system locations by default.

[File access and permissions (Windows Runtime apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)